# How to share a java application for the clients without an installer?

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-plugin, share, java-web-start

I have a java application that uses swing and I would like to share it on my website, so that users who have no JRE on their computers can open it.

First, I naively thought that a link to download a .jar was enough but now I realize that it needs a JRE to be launched properly. 
So then, I looked for other solutions and I searched information for the applets, until I understood that it was now obsolete.

Eventually, I tried to understand that Java Web Start thing but I am completely lost, as it needs several files to be created and to setup the server. The tutorials I found weren't very clear... As I am an Eclipse user, I tried to look for a plugin that would do this automatically but I cannot find anything.

Do you know a plugin or is there a simpler possibility to share this very simple java application in a website ? Or do I have to try and try again to deploy my application through Java web start.

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Java Web Start **still** requires your users have a JRE on their computer. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2970947)

Comment: You can write a complete Eclipse RCP which includes a JRE as part of the app, but that isn't small or simple. Whatever you do there always has to be a JRE on the computer.

Comment: Even if I manage somehow to use java web start ?

Comment: To run Java there must **always** be a JRE on the computer, no exceptions.